# test - linux command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm just wondering about `test` Linux command.

Is there an output from `test -f FILE` that I could grab using a variable?

How do I know whether this `test` perform successfully or not?

Comment: So what shell? csh, bash, sh, ksh,...

Comment: @EdHeal I'm using bash

Comment: `if test -f FILE; then echo "test returnd true"; else echo "test returnd false"; fi` See: `help test`

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you cyrus!

Comment: test -f file && echo "Yes, that's true." || echo "No, that's false."

Answer (score 2):

The `test` command sets its exit code.  You can examine the value in `$?` but usually you don't have to.  Instead, you use a control flow construct such as `while` or `if` which does this behind the scenes for you.

```
while test -e "$myfile"; do
   if grep -q 'fnord' "$myfile"; then
       echo "Success!  Play again."
       dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 | base64 >"$myfile"
   else
       break
   fi
done
```

Observe how `while` examines the exit code from `test` and `if` examines the exit code from `grep`.  Each of these programs -- and generally any useful Unix utility -- is written so that it returns a zero exit code on success, otherwise a non-zero value.

`test` is perhaps somewhat odd in that that's *all* it does.  Historically, it was a bit of a kitchen sink to avoid having to burden the shell's syntax with a lot of string and file property tests (which may in retrospect have been a slightly unhappy design decision -- this trips up beginners still today).

You also see a lot of beginners who have not picked up this idiom, and write pretzel code like

```
test -e "$myfile"
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
    ....
```

Yo dawg, I hear you like running `test` so I run `test` to `test` the output from the first `test`.